# Display modal while files are uploading

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an c# MVC application that I'm building, and I'm wondering how to display a modal, containing a please wait message, while files are being uploaded.

I've searched Goggle and this site a lot but I could use some more direct feedback.

I've created the modal in my index.cshtml but am unsure how to display it during the upload process.   I tried using something like this in my submit button but it doesn't post the form then.

```
 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
```

This is my code.

Index.cshtml

```
<h4>Please fill out the form below and select at least one file to upload.</h4>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h5>Your Name:</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" name="uname" class="form-control" required placeholder="John Smith">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h5>Your Email:</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required placeholder="test@test.com">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h5>Your Company:</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" name="company" class="form-control" required placeholder="Test Company, Inc">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h5>Choose file(s) to upload (Max 500MB):</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input name="files" type="file" id="files" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h5></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                Please wait while we are uploading your files
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then here is my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace vidup.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(List<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
            var userName = Request["uname"].ToString();
            var userEmail = Request["email"].ToString();
            var userCompany = Request["company"].ToString();
            ViewBag.Username = userName;
            ViewBag.UserCompany = userCompany;
            ViewBag.UserEmail = userEmail;
            int i = 0;

            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), userCompany, userName, DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy h-mm-tt"));
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase item in files)
            {
                i++;
                if (item != null && item.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(item.FileName);
                    var fullPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
                    ViewBag.Message3 = fileName;
                    ViewBag.Message4 = fullPath;
                    try
                    {
                        item.SaveAs(fullPath);
                        var fileCount = i + " File(s) uploaded successfully";
                        ViewBag.Message = fileCount;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        ViewBag.Message = e;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "No File selected";
                }
            }




            return View("Status");
        }
    }
}
```

finally the status.cshtml

```
<h2>Upload Status</h2>

<h4>Thank you, @ViewBag.UserName from @ViewBag.UserCompany</h4>
<P>Your file upload returned a status of: @ViewBag.Message</P>
<p>An Email has been sent to @ViewBag.UserEmail with the status of this upload.</p>
<br/>
<a href="@Url.Action("Index")" class="btn btn-primary">Click here to upload again</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your submit button does not post the form anymore is because the attributes you put in it are overriding its default behaviour - you would need to add an onclick handler to it to also start the form submit in addition to the modal show. Give your submit button an ID and give your form an ID.. after that its a straightforward onclick method

```
$('buttonid').on('click', function()
{
  $('#formid').submit();
});
```

This tells your button to submit the form whenever it is clicked

Comment: This is what i've got, but it is not working.  `<script>
    document.getElementById('sbmtBtn').on('click', function ()
    {
        $('#upldFrm').submit();
    });
</script>`

Comment: Well, must have been a cache issue cause its working now on an incognito window of chrome.

Comment: along the same note, Is there a way to easily display the percentage that chrome displays in the bottom right as its uploading as the percentage of the progress bar?  see this image for reference [link](http://i.imgur.com/xUuqwPp.jpg)

Comment: Not by default by you can create your own progress bars easily enough.., But I don't think you can ever know the exact time it will take the file to get uploaded so i think you will get sometimes when the page navigates away before it gets to 100%

Comment: Well I opened a new Question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594991/display-upload-progress-in-modal-with-bootstrap-progress-bar) on this topic, if you know any one that could help.