# Display Upload Progress in Modal with Bootstrap Progress Bar

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have an c# MVC application that I'm building, that presents a form and allows the user to upload some files. When the user clicks submit a modal appears with a progress bar, set to 100% and displays a message of "please wait, ect. "

I want to be able to capture the progress of the upload process and display it in the modal's progress bar.

So after a bit of Google searches I've come up with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545780/bootstrap-progress-bar-for-mvc-file-upload), but I'm unsure how to adapt it to my current situation.

Here is my Code:

Index.cshtml

```
<h4>Please fill out the form below and select at least one file to upload.</h4>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "upldFrm" }))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h5>Your Name:</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" name="uname" class="form-control" required placeholder="John Smith">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h5>Your Email:</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required placeholder="test@test.com">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h5>Your Company:</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" name="company" class="form-control" required placeholder="Test Company, Inc">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h5>Choose file(s) to upload (Max 500MB):</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input name="files" type="file" id="files" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h5></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="sbmtBtn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>Uploading...</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Please wait while we are uploading your files
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('sbmtBtn').on('click', function ()
    {
        $('#upldFrm').submit();
    });
</script>
```

Here is my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace vidup.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(List<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
            var userName = Request["uname"].ToString();
            var userEmail = Request["email"].ToString();
            var userCompany = Request["company"].ToString();
            ViewBag.Username = userName;
            ViewBag.UserCompany = userCompany;
            ViewBag.UserEmail = userEmail;
            int i = 0;

            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), userCompany, userName, DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy h-mm-tt"));
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase item in files)
            {
                i++;
                if (item != null && item.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(item.FileName);
                    var fullPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
                    ViewBag.Message3 = fileName;
                    ViewBag.Message4 = fullPath;
                    try
                    {
                        item.SaveAs(fullPath);
                        var fileCount = i + " File(s) uploaded successfully";
                        ViewBag.Message = fileCount;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        ViewBag.Message = e;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "No File selected";
                }
            }
            return View("Status");
        }

        public ActionResult Status()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried to add in the code from the post i provided, but im getting a error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: formdata is not defined
```

This is what my view looks like now, can anyone direct me on why I'm getting this error? Or how to resolve it?

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h5>Choose file(s) to upload (Max 500MB):</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input name="files" type="file" id="files" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h5></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="sbmtBtn" name="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitForm()"/>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>Uploading...</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Please wait while we are uploading your files
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function submitForm() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        var file=document.getElementById('files').files[0];
        var formData = new FormData();
        formdata.append("file_name", file);
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
        ajax.open("POST", '@Url.Action("Index","Home")', true)
        ajax.send(formdata);
    }

    function progressHandler(event){
        var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
        $('.bar').width(percent);
    }

    function completeHandler(){
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        $('.bar').width(100);
    }

    //$('sbmtBtn').on('click', function ()
    //{
    //    $('#upldFrm').submit();
    //});
</script>
```

Comment: Can anyone help with this? or point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is something up for debate but the progress bar is really just to show the user something is happening IMO. Many have moved away from using actual progress and just showing a "loading wheel" or something to that effect. There is a lot of overhead to have an accurate progress bar and little added value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following code to get the Progress bar and still have the controller do the work for uploading the file.

In the Head I included these scripts

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Then the body of the form and the scripts.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <h5>Your Name:</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" name="uname" class="form-control" required placeholder="John Smith">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <h5>Your Email:</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required placeholder="test@test.com">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <h5>Your Company:</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" name="company" class="form-control" required placeholder="Test Company, Inc">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <h5>Choose file(s) to upload (Max 500MB):</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input name="files" type="file" id="files" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <h5></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="sbmtBtn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <br />
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar">0%</div>
    </div>

    <div id="status"></div>

    <script>
        (function () {
            var bar = $('.progress-bar');
            var percent = $('.progress-bar');
            var status = $('#status');

            $('form').ajaxForm({
                beforeSend: function () {
                    status.empty();
                    status.html("Please Wait While We Upload Your File(s)");
                    var percentValue = '0%';
                    bar.width(percentValue);
                    percent.html(percentValue);
                },
                uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                    var percentValue = percentComplete + '%';
                    bar.width(percentValue);
                    percent.html(percentValue);
                },
                success: function (d) {
                    var percentValue = '100%';
                    bar.width(percentValue);
                    percent.html(percentValue);
                    $('#fu1').val('');
                    status.empty();
                    alert(d);
                },
                complete: function (xhr) {
                    status.html("You can Upload again or close this page.");
                }
            });
        })();
    </script>
```

Comment: Me likey Mr. Greyhammer